# Conversion issues from VB.NET to C# for my Log in

Tags: c#

Ok I have some VB code that does my Log in and I want it to now work in C#. I thought this would be pretty straight forward, however I was wrong. The line:  string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnection").ConnectionString; is throwing an error at ConnectionStrings and I can't figure out why. Also in the while statement the objDR says that it it is a variable but is being used as a method. Any help would be great.  The following is the entire code:

```
Using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void  
    btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {



        if (((string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text))))
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Username must be entered.";

            txtUserName.Focus();

            return;

        }



        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnection").ConnectionString;



        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString);

        string sql = "Select * From TCustomers";



        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader objDR = default(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader);

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand objCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);

        myConnection.Open();


        objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);



        bool blnLogin = false;



        string strPassword = null;

        string strUserName = null;



        strPassword = txtPassword.Text;

        strPassword = strPassword.Trim();

        strUserName = txtUserName.Text;

        strUserName = strUserName.Trim();




        while (objDR.Read())
        {

            if (((objDR("strUserName").ToString().Trim() == strUserName)) & ((objDR("strPassword").ToString().Trim() == strPassword)))
            {


                blnLogin = true;


                Session["CustomerID"] = objDR("intCustomerID");

                Session["UserName"] = objDR("strUserName");

                Session["FirstName"] = objDR("strFirstName");

                Session["LastName"] = objDR("strLastName");

                Session["Email"] = objDR("strEmailAddress");

                Session["UserType"] = objDR("intUserTypeID");





                break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit While



            }



        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `objDR("strUserName").`  isn't even valid C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB, there is no syntax difference between a method call or an array access, they both use `(argument)`.  In C# however, arrays use `[]`.  This is not properly converted with automatic/rote conversion because it's impossible to tell the difference, so you have to fix it yourself:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
                                      ^              ^ convert to [] array access
```

Same with accessing the properties of the DataRow:

```
objDR["strUserName"]
     ^             ^ Convert to [] array access
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I found in your code is the following:

```
objDR("strUserName")
```

You need to use

```
objDR["strUserName"]
```

Change all occurrences from parenthesis to brackets

That explains the error with the "objDR says that it it is a variable but is being used as a method. "